# Build histogram from aggregation result

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

### My data

`{ "city":"New York",      "street":"Atlantic Avenue" }
{ "city":"New York",      "street":"Hudson Street" }
{ "city":"New York",      "street":"Fawn Court" }
{ "city":"Boston",        "street":"Atlantic Avenue" }
{ "city":"Boston",        "street":"Hudson Street" }
{ "city":"Boston",        "street":"7th Avenue" }
{ "city":"Washington DC", "street":"Atlantic Avenue" }
{ "city":"Washington DC", "street":"Dogwood Drive" }
{ "city":"Washington DC", "street":"7th Avenue" }`

If we count each time that a street appears, we will get the following:

`| Street name     | Number of times |
|-----------------|-----------------|
| Atlantic Avenue |               3 |
| Hudson Street   |               2 |
| 7th Avenue      |               2 |
| Hudson Street   |               1 |
| Dogwood Drive   |               1 |`

### My goal

I want to build a histogram that says how many street names are unique, how many are seen twice, and so on...

To do so, I should get the result of a **Terms Aggregation** and send it to a **Histogram Aggregation**.

Here is the result for the example above:

`| Street name count | Number of times |
|-------------------|-----------------|
|                 1 |               2 |
|                 2 |               2 |
|                 3 |               1 |`

### What I have already done

I have build the first table with Kibana and this query:

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index1/type1/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_street": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "street"
      }
    }
  }
}'`

Then I tried to add this results to a histogram:

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/fingerprint/user/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "histogram_streets": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "group_by_street>_count",
        "interval": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_street": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "street"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'`

However, I retrieve an empty bucket.

Any idea of how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this field name is wrong: `group_by_street>_count`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Phil I want to build the histogram based on the "doc_count" field of the "group_by_street" aggregation.

Comment: Any news on that issue? I am looking for exactly that. I want a histogram of the result of a terms aggregation performed beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to build the histogram based on the "doc_count" field of the "group_by_street" aggregation

ES aggregations are document based, meaning you can use a bucket aggregation to group by a field on documents and then further aggregate inside each bucket as a nested aggregation on another document field. You can use scripts to combine document fields in novel ways, but I've never seen a capability to aggregate *on the number of buckets* or the *number of documents in a bucket*.

The only place I'm aware of a path notation like `group_by_street>_count` working is for specifying the sort path in a nested aggregation as [documented here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting_based_on_deep_metrics.html).

I would suggest you create the histogram client side from the terms aggregation result. In a way, the terms aggregation *is already* a history as it tells you directly the number of documents that have each term. You just need to order each bucket tuple (term, doc_count) in a way meaningful for you. I'm not sure you can do this directly in kibana or not.